# How can a non-default service account be set in GKE using Terraform?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to set a non-default Service Account to the node pool that I am creating.

However, every time with the following code, the node pool shows as using the `default` service account.

```
resource "google_container_node_pool" "node_pool" {
...
service_account = "myserviceaccount@<id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
    ]
}
```

When I check on the GKE console it shows the Service Account as `default` rather than my specified account.

I have confirmed in the console, that a node group can be manually created with `myserviceaccount` set as the Service Account for the node group.  It is only with Terraform this is not working.

How do I set my own service account when creating the node pool?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear from your question whether your `service_account` is, as required, part of the `node_config` which is part of resource.

See [example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster#example-usage---with-a-separately-managed-node-pool-recommended)

Comment: You are on the right track with this answer. Do not specify the service account by email address. If the service account does not exist, add a **google_service_account** resource to the HCL and specify that resource in **google_container_node_pool**. If the service account already exists add a **google_service_account** via a **data** resource.

Comment: Thanks! I seemed to get this working, but now, I get an error: 
 error looking up service account namespace/myserviceaccount: serviceaccount "myserviceaccount" not found
It definitely is not a typo. So I'm trying to figure out if there's anything else required to enable the service account.

Comment: Did you see @john-hanley comment? If the Service Account does not exist, it must be created beforehand.

Comment: If the service account already exists, reference one with this data resource: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/service_account If the service account does not exist, create one with this resource: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_service_account

Comment: Then declare the service account in **google_container_node_pool** like this: **service_account = google_service_account.sa_resource_name.email**

Comment: Thank you all! What I found was that I didn't create an associated service account in the namespace, only at the IAM level.